# Pandas Groupby with Categorical Columns returns NaN

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

There are no NaN in the pandas dataframe, and when I look at each group of the groupby, they only have the Int64Index, and none of the rest of the non-groupby columns. I am baffled.

### What am I missing?

**Here is a reproducible code:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "a": np.random.rand(1000),
    "b": np.random.rand(1000),
    "c": np.random.rand(1000)
})

ranges = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
df["a_bin"] = pd.cut(df.a, ranges)
df["b_bin"] = pd.cut(df.b, ranges)

print(df.groupby(["a_bin", "b_bin"]).c.mean())
```

**and here is the result:**

```
a_bin          b_bin           
(0.0, 0.0101]  (0.0, 0.0101]      NaN
               (0.0101, 0.0202]   NaN
               (0.0202, 0.0303]   NaN
               (0.0303, 0.0404]   NaN
               (0.0404, 0.0505]   NaN
                                   ..
(0.99, 1.0]    (0.949, 0.96]      NaN
               (0.96, 0.97]       NaN
               (0.97, 0.98]       NaN
               (0.98, 0.99]       NaN
               (0.99, 1.0]        NaN
Name: c, Length: 9801, dtype: float64
```

> My pandas version is: 1.0.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are all possible combinations of categories, unused categories create missing values, check [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#operations).

So if need remove mising values:

```
print(df.groupby(["a_bin", "b_bin"]).c.mean().dropna())
a_bin          b_bin           
(0.0, 0.0101]  (0.0, 0.0101]       0.381681
               (0.0505, 0.0606]    0.148762
               (0.0909, 0.101]     0.313093
               (0.101, 0.111]      0.488104
               (0.313, 0.323]      0.518599

(0.99, 1.0]    (0.505, 0.515]      0.149027
               (0.576, 0.586]      0.099652
               (0.778, 0.788]      0.220360
               (0.828, 0.838]      0.166424
               (0.97, 0.98]        0.516558
Name: c, Length: 948, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of unused categories you check the count of each group using `df.groupby(['a_bin','b_bin']).c.count()`. Nice answer. +1

Comment: Wow, awesome. In general, I guess it is the "Categorical" nature of the column which causes all such non-existent groups to be created. In normal groupby, only the items that are as part of the key will get a value. Thanks for helping me keep my sanity :) +1

Answer (score 5):

As the previous answer suggested, you can simply use dropna() on the result.  However, if you have many unused categories, the intermediate computation will have a huge number of nan values (especially when using multiple indices) which may ruin your performance.

Instead, in your call to [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) you should set the argument "observed" to True which will prevent the nan values from being generated.

```
print(df.groupby(["a_bin", "b_bin"], observed = True).c.mean())
```